# why $fetch is not working inside asyncData()/fetch()?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

```js
async asyncData(){
    try {
        const response = await $fetch(this.apiUrl+'/api/get-list-of-industries')
        console.log(response);
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
},
```

I am using Laravel as backend and Nuxt 3 as frontend. here i am trying to fetch all the data from given api. this "$fetch()" works if i use inside "async mounted()", but it does not work inside "async asyncData()" or "async fetch()". what i am trying to do is, i am fetching data from backend to a nuxt page, and i want to them to work as SSR. i even install @nuxt/axios, but it seems it doesn't work for nuxt 3. because i tried to use @nuxt/axios, it didn't work. i watched many tutorials, they are inserting '@nuxt/axios' inside "modules:[]" in nuxt.config.js. I even created a file name "nuxt.config.js" which is not given by default in nuxt 3. in nuxt 3 "_____.ts" file is given. i even tried to insert "modules:['@nuxt/axios']", but it shows error whenever i insert modules:[] here! can anybody help me please? i got stuck on it for 3-4 days now.

Comment: No. i could not. I switch to lower nuxt version. to 2.15.7. fetch() in nuxt 2. but it need to be used in a different way.

Comment: You switch from Nuxt 3 to Nuxt 2?

Comment: yeah unfortunately.